# Error Code: 1055. Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, mysql

```
SELECT * FROM db_hr.employee
WHERE salary > (
    SELECT AVG(salary)
    FROM db_hr.employee
)
GROUP BY salary;
```

What wrong with the query? it give me an error :

> Error Code: 1055. Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'db_hr.employee.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

I'm trying to display employee data with salary more than avg of salary and group it by salary

Comment: Please never use `*` when also using `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Note that a window function might be more efficient here. Also `> AVG` is not the same as the median...

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you just want to find records of employees having salaries greater than the average.  If so, then the `GROUP BY` clause is superfluous.  Remove it, and use this version:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM db_hr.employee
WHERE salary > (SELECT AVG(salary) FROM db_hr.employee);
```

By the way, regarding the use of `GROUP BY`, if a query is not selecting any aggregates of columns, or there is no goal to remove duplicates, then the `GROUP BY` may be unnecessary.